# Choosing between -ing and -tion or -age

Tags: ing

There are many cases that I have to choose between the -ing form of a verb and the -tion or - age nouns.
Like this question:

Local waves within the harbor make ...... difficult, if not impossible.
1. anchoring
2. anchorage

Which one is correct?
Is this because of grammer, or meaning, or common usage?

Answer (score 2):

The usage of **anchorage** in your example is incorrect. The words **anchorage** and **anchoring** are not interchangeable. One is an action, the other a location or place.

**an·chor·age**
ˈaNGk(ə)rij
noun

1. an area that is suitable for a ship to anchor in.
2. (*historical*) an anchorite's dwelling place.

Now, substitute the word **anchorage** with **the area**:

> Local waves within the harbor make **the area** difficult, if not impossible.

As you can see, that sentence is incomplete.

> Local waves within the harbor make **anchoring|fishing|swimming** difficult, if not impossible.

An action can be made more difficult, but not a place/location.